# Include 3rd party library's source maps in Webpack

Tags: webpack, next.js, source-maps

I have a NextJS project, and it depends on a 3rd party library. The library comes with source map file. In other words it's NPM package includes two files

- lib.mjs
- lib.mjs.map

But when I build my project the output source map file doesn't seem to include the informations from `lib.mjs.map`, and I don't see any readable stack trace when an exceptions happens from the library.

How can I configure NextJS so the final source map file includes the library's source map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to include 3rd party library’s source maps in Next.js is to use the **source-map-loader** in your webpack config.
For example, you can add something like this in your `next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.mjs$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      use: ['source-map-loader'],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

This will tell webpack to load the source maps from the .mjs files and include them in the output bundle. You also need to enable source maps generation in production by setting `productionBrowserSourceMaps: true` in your `next.config.js` file.